# How I can access postgres log_connections logs

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I see that log_connections enabled by default on Heroku PostgreSQL instance, but how I can get this log?

Answer (score 1):

This setting in heroku enables connection logging in Postgres per: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-CONNECTIONS.

You can find the logged info in the `pg_stat_activity` table in your DB.